# Win10 freezes on boot. ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000420 - An assertion failure has occurred

Tags: windows-10, debug, acpi, windbg

So I've been trying to track down an issue with a computer. Win7 boots fine, unless multi-threading is disabled in bios, then it freezes on the load screen. I'm not sure why that would be.

Anyways, with Win10 it almost always freezes on the load screen with the spinning circles. When it doesn't freeze and I let it sit it eventually gets a DPC Watchdog Violation BSOD, restarts, then freezes. I've done a ton or testing while would take WAY to long to type, but after it all I suspect maybe its a driver. So I put a debug/checked ACPI.sys build on the OS and start debugging through WinDbg and I get the following error below. Any ideas where I should look from here?

One random time I did get a BSOD with the Driver_power_state_failure error and at that time WinDbg said it could have been caused by USB3.sys. Maybe that's important, maybe it was a one-off I'm not sure yet.

```
0: kd> g
Continuing an assertion failure can result in the debuggee
being terminated (bugchecking for kernel debuggees).
If you want to ignore this assertion, use 'ahi'.
If you want to force continuation, use 'gh' or 'gn'.
0: kd> gh
FFFFE001E95CC880 160000  - PnpBiosGetDeviceResourceList failed for Device 0XFFFFE001EA0C0C40, Status 0xc0000001
KDTARGET: Refreshing KD connection
Assertion: The BIOS has reported inconsistent resources (_CRS).  Please upgrade your BIOS.
ACPI!PnpBiosGetDeviceResourceList+0x154:
fffff801`377f907c cd2c            int     2Ch
2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Unknown bugcheck code (0)
Unknown bugcheck description
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000
Arg2: 0000000000000000
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 0

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.162.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160223-1728

DUMP_TYPE:  0

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

PROCESS_NAME:  System

FAULTING_IP: 
ACPI!PnpBiosGetDeviceResourceList+154
fffff801`377f907c cd2c            int     2Ch

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000420 - An assertion failure has occurred.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000420 - An assertion failure has occurred.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000420

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: 8f7

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3d

CPU_STEPPING: 4

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3d,4,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 22'00000000 (cache) 22'00000000 (init)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x0

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  TYLER-PC

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  03-07-2019 14:05:14.0767

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.17763.132 amd64fre

LOCK_ADDRESS:  fffff801ced6e440 -- (!locks fffff801ced6e440)

Resource @ nt!PiEngineLock (0xfffff801ced6e440)    Exclusively owned
    Contention Count = 3
    NumberOfExclusiveWaiters = 1
     Threads: ffffe001ea08d040-01<*> 

     Threads Waiting On Exclusive Access:
              ffffe001ea12d040       
1 total locks

PNP_TRIAGE_DATA: 
    Lock address  : 0xfffff801ced6e440
    Thread Count  : 1
    Thread address: 0xffffe001ea08d040
    Thread wait   : 0x1b7

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff801377f97f0 to fffff801377f907c

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd000`4499f1a0 fffff801`377f97f0 : ffffe001`ea0c0c40 00000000`80000001 ffffd000`4499f278 ffffe001`e89c1b90 : ACPI!PnpBiosGetDeviceResourceList+0x154
ffffd000`4499f240 fffff801`377efef3 : ffffe001`ea0c0c40 ffffc001`41ed4590 ffffd000`4499f2f0 ffffe001`e95cc8e8 : ACPI!PnpBiosUpdateResourceListWithSidebandResources+0x48
ffffd000`4499f2c0 fffff801`3772470c : ffffe001`ea0c0c40 ffffe001`e89c1b90 ffffe001`e89c1b90 ffffd000`4499f3b0 : ACPI!ACPIFilterIrpFilterResourceRequirements+0x183
ffffd000`4499f340 fffff801`37559181 : ffffe001`ea0c0c40 ffffe001`e89c1b90 ffffd000`4499f510 ffffe001`ea4f5960 : ACPI!ACPIDispatchIrp+0x19c
ffffd000`4499f3e0 fffff801`37558729 : ffffe001`ea4f5960 00000000`000007ff ffffd000`4499f6c8 00000000`00000001 : Wdf01000!FxPkgFdo::SendIrpSynchronously+0x91 [d:\th\minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\pnp\fxpkgfdo.cpp @ 271] 
ffffd000`4499f440 fffff801`3754dff2 : ffffe001`e883a140 ffffe001`ea4f5960 ffffd000`4499f659 00000000`00000801 : Wdf01000!FxPkgFdo::PnpFilterResourceRequirements+0x61 [d:\th\minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\pnp\km\fxpkgfdokm.cpp @ 136] 
ffffd000`4499f4a0 fffff801`375411b1 : ffffe001`e89c1b90 ffffe001`ea678700 ffffe001`ea57d890 fffff801`ceb66953 : Wdf01000!FxPkgPnp::Dispatch+0xb2 [d:\th\minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\pnp\fxpkgpnp.cpp @ 654] 
ffffd000`4499f510 fffff801`cef58df2 : ffffd000`4499f659 ffffd000`4499f659 ffffe001`ea57d890 00000000`00000004 : Wdf01000!FxDevice::DispatchWithLock+0x111 [d:\th\minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\core\fxdevice.cpp @ 1402] 
ffffd000`4499f570 fffff801`cef5bf43 : ffffc001`41ed4590 ffffd000`4499f720 ffffc001`41ed51e8 ffffc001`0000066f : nt!IopFilterResourceRequirementsCall+0xb2
ffffd000`4499f5e0 fffff801`cef58c49 : ffffc001`41ed4300 ffffc001`0000003c ffffe001`e89a6540 ffffe001`e89a6540 : nt!IopQueryDeviceResources+0x173
ffffd000`4499f6c0 fffff801`cef5834c : fffff801`00000000 fffff801`00000004 00000000`00000000 ffffc001`41ed5710 : nt!PnpGetResourceRequirementsForAssignTable+0xb9
ffffd000`4499f720 fffff801`ceef4b0a : 00000000`00000003 ffffe001`e889b940 00000000`00000000 ffffc001`41ed5710 : nt!PnpAllocateResources+0x7c
ffffd000`4499f790 fffff801`cef439ad : ffffe001`e9519910 ffffd000`4499f8e0 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`00000000 : nt!PnpProcessAssignResources+0x11e
ffffd000`4499f7e0 fffff801`cefb8a05 : ffffe001`e9519910 ffffd000`4499fb19 00000000`00000000 fffff801`cef42953 : nt!PipProcessDevNodeTree+0xa1
ffffd000`4499fa60 fffff801`ceb4f9da : 00000001`00000003 fffff801`ced6cee0 ffffe001`e951a808 ffffe001`e884b180 : nt!PiProcessStartSystemDevices+0x59
ffffd000`4499fab0 fffff801`ceac86a9 : ffffe001`ea08d040 fffff801`ced6cee0 fffff801`cee0a340 ffffe001`ea27e948 : nt!PnpDeviceActionWorker+0x362
ffffd000`4499fb80 fffff801`ceb5a895 : 00000005`bd9bbfff 00000000`00000080 ffffe001`e88ca680 ffffe001`ea08d040 : nt!ExpWorkerThread+0xe9
ffffd000`4499fc10 fffff801`cebbe906 : ffffd000`445ce180 ffffe001`ea08d040 fffff801`ceb5a854 ffffc001`3e0c3c28 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x41
ffffd000`4499fc60 00000000`00000000 : ffffd000`449a0000 ffffd000`4499a000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  f7b40f0e51c2e11408c77609da2fb1776906f89a

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  c48b64220fa6e6d42d9557abb54b983308a784cb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  3edfca7a76ee17d6861471169e0f5fcff58fac1c

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
ACPI!PnpBiosGetDeviceResourceList+154
fffff801`377f907c cd2c            int     2Ch

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  8b482ccd

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  ACPI!PnpBiosGetDeviceResourceList+154

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: ACPI

IMAGE_NAME:  ACPI.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5632da86

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10586.0

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  154

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x0_ACPI!PnpBiosGetDeviceResourceList

BUCKET_ID:  0x0_ACPI!PnpBiosGetDeviceResourceList

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x0_ACPI!PnpBiosGetDeviceResourceList

TARGET_TIME:  2019-03-07T18:04:35.000Z

OSBUILD:  10586

OSSERVICEPACK:  162

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-02-24 00:48:00

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160223-1728

BUILDLAB_STR:  th2_release_sec

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.162.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160223-1728

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  738

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x0_acpi!pnpbiosgetdeviceresourcelist

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {a06efe28-59b8-2dc9-c230-969a548e7d9e}
```

Comment: More than likely you need a bios upgrade to be compatible with W10. Make and model of PC?

Comment: Its actually a custom PC I've been trying to troubleshoot. By custom I mean it's not a consumer product, it's pretty much an intel reference board. I can actually compile my own BIOS for it. What would have to be changed in order to make it compatible? Or how could I troubleshoot it to figure out whats not compatible? Unfortunately I'm more of a hardware guy.

Comment: I would install the latest bios from Intel. There may not be a compatible bios available, plenty of older PCs are being left in the dirt when it comes to W10.